# What is the difference between 気にしない and 気にすることない

Tags: nuances

What is the difference between 気にしない and 気にすることない

My bad, not enough context.
The first one is 、気にしないでね。at the end of the sentence after comma. The second one is a separate sentence 気にすることないわ。at the end of a phrase. Seems like they mean same thing. I encountered 気にしないで multiple times, whereas this is the first time I see 気にすることない. This is why I am asking.

Comment: As a stand alone sentence? In reply to what?

Comment: I would generally interpret しない as "doesn't" and することない as "can't" (literally, the act of doing it doesn't exist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you realize that しないで in 気にしないでね is one part and should not be separated?

しないで is one of the te-forms of しない, the other being しなくて. Te-form has several functions, and the one being used here is to make requests. When making requests, people prefer しないで over しなくて, so the sentence 気にしないでね is requesting the other party to not mind.

> 気にしないでね。　Please don't mind.

Then, the other one 気にすることないわ has no element of request in it, so the speaker is talking about self. "I will not mind." It's pretty much the same thing as 気にしない, both mean "I don't mind", but 気にすることない has a stronger emphasis, and indicates that the speaker is not just not mining now, but also won't mind in the future. Let's translate them literally into English and see:

> 気にしない I don't mind. (or I won't mind)
> 気にすることない　The action of me minding doesn't exist.

See how the second one brings a stronger emphasis? I know for a English speaker, the second sentence sounds redundant and too wordy, but that's literally what the Japanese sentence means, and in Japanese, it's a perfectly fine sentence, not redundant or wordy at all.